# MySQL Query works in PHPMyAdmin but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been trying to get for examples rows 100 through 200 from a table of 1000+ rows.  I found this snippet online that seems to work perfectly in PHPMyAdmin but when I try to use it in code, it won't work.

```
    SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, id
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, myGames
    ) ranked 
WHERE rownum >= 100 AND rownum < 200"
```

Here is my PHP Code

```
$q = "SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, id
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, myGames
    ) ranked 
WHERE rownum >= 100 AND rownum < 200";

$query = mysql_query($q);
```

When I try to do $query = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error()), I get nothing.

Any help with this is greatly appriciated

EDIT:  SOLVED by using LIMIT 100,100.  Thanks guys

Comment: Does any query from code work?

Comment: Does `$query` return a value? tried a `var_dump($query)` to check that it's actually failing?

Comment: Why not just use `LIMIT 100,100`? That'd give you the 100-200 result range, without the extra sub-queries...

Comment: mysql_*() functions are to no longer be used and will be removed in future releases. Please us MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retrieve a subset of your result set, use [limit offset, num_rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

```
select id
from myGames
limit 100, 100;
```